Finding Resolution/Frame Rate/Bitrate limitation for codecs that does not have profile/level concept(ex: VP8)
As per the documentation of VP9 Codec in Wikipedia VP9 has the concept of Profile and Level. Based on these profiles and levels it also has some limitations on Resolution/Frame Rate/ Bitrate as follows,

Here I get the concept clearly.
So now I want to know about the limitations of codecs which does not have profile and level concepts. How/Where I can find this? (Not found in the Wikipedia documentation)
